# Truezip umout() failed, "cannot delete temporary file"

Tags: truezip

Anybody knows, why this could happen? When calling TFile.umount() an error occured:

```
de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsSyncException: part:file:/C:/Data/Backup/New%20Backups/F20120805T070000Z.part!/
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.archive.FsTargetArchiveController.close(FsTargetArchiveController.java:623)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.archive.FsTargetArchiveController.sync0(FsTargetArchiveController.java:472)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.archive.FsTargetArchiveController.sync(FsTargetArchiveController.java:460)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.archive.FsContextController.sync(FsContextController.java:236)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsResourceController.sync(FsResourceController.java:84)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsCacheController.sync(FsCacheController.java:220)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsDecoratingController.sync(FsDecoratingController.java:148)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsLockController$1Sync.call(FsLockController.java:381)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsLockController$1Sync.call(FsLockController.java:370)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsLockController.locked(FsLockController.java:166)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsLockController.writeLocked(FsLockController.java:108)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsLockController.sync(FsLockController.java:394)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsDecoratingController.sync(FsDecoratingController.java:148)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.archive.zip.KeyManagerController.sync(KeyManagerController.java:125)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsDecoratingController.sync(FsDecoratingController.java:148)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsFalsePositiveController.sync(FsFalsePositiveController.java:516)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsManager.sync(FsManager.java:139)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsManager.sync(FsManager.java:100)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.file.TVFS.sync(TVFS.java:284)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.file.TVFS.sync(TVFS.java:231)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.file.TFile.sync(TFile.java:949)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.file.TFile.umount(TFile.java:997)
.
.
.
Caused by: java.io.IOException: C:\Data\Backup\New Backups\F20120805T070000Z.part.8228029877339677208.tmp (cannot delete temporary file)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.file.TempFilePool$Buffer.pool(TempFilePool.java:80)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.file.TempFilePool$Buffer.release(TempFilePool.java:70)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.file.FileOutputSocket.release(FileOutputSocket.java:126)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.file.FileOutputSocket.close(FileOutputSocket.java:97)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.file.FileOutputSocket.access$100(FileOutputSocket.java:28)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.file.FileOutputSocket$1OutputStream.close(FileOutputSocket.java:153)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.io.DecoratingOutputStream.close(DecoratingOutputStream.java:65)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.zip.RawZipOutputStream.close(RawZipOutputStream.java:696)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.archive.zip.ZipOutputShop.close(ZipOutputShop.java:250)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.archive.FsMultiplexedOutputShop.close(FsMultiplexedOutputShop.java:169)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.socket.DisconnectingOutputShop.close(DisconnectingOutputShop.java:107)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.socket.LockOutputShop.close(LockOutputShop.java:68)
    at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.archive.FsTargetArchiveController.close(FsTargetArchiveController.java:618)
    ... 26 more
```

I know that this is due to the tmp file cannot be removed. But why this could happen?

Comment: Just to double check: Please make sure to use the latest version TrueZIP 7.6

Answer (score 0):

Are you probably concurrently observing the directory, e.g. in Windows Explorer? Some Explorer extensions access files for inspection. If this happens concurrently, then the JVM cannot delete the temp file because Windows does not allow that.

I can tell you are running on Java 6. If you switch to Java 7, then you should get a more detailed exception which may help to check my assumption.